# How to take a non continuous sub array. By consolidating multiple .copyOf range

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array. Lets say this array is called numberCards. it is defined as {0,1,2,5,6,10,42} I want to talk an array which consits of indices (2-4 (inclusive)) and indices 7 and  8. Is there a way to do this in as few lines as possible?

Comment: Given an array of indices, you can do this with a single for loop.

Comment: so there is no way to "concatenate two arrays"

Comment: Well, arrays are fixed size, so you'll have to create a new one and copy the content into it. `Arrays.copyOfRange` could help but it's probably easier to do it with a for loop as your range of indices is not contiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to extract a sub set of values or the change the order.

```
public static <T> T[] select(T[] ts, int... indecies) {
    T[] copy = (T[]) new Object[indecies.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < indecies.length; i++)
         copy[i] = ts[indecies[i]];
    return copy;
}
```